# canvas free drawing and adding shapes

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

i'm trying to creating a free drawing tool with the option to add shapes to the canvas. the user will have buttons at the bottom of the canvas with shapes. if he click on a circle, than a circle will add to the canvas with the option to scale it and move around the canvas.

my problem is when i add a shape and than try to click on it to move it, the canvas draw instead of selecting the shape.

i'm trying to work with fabric.js but i don't see in their demo how to have both.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my app by having two Canvas areas on the page. In my case I named the first one "prep" and the actual drawing area one "stage"

```
 <div class="col-sm-2"> 
    <canvas id="prep" width="150" height="500" style= "border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <canvas id="stage" width="650" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then, I added a mouse:down event to the prep area. If a shape is clicked in the 'prep' area, a cloned object gets added to the 'stage' area.

```
prep.on('mouse:down', function(options){
if(options.target) {
    if (fabric.util.getKlass(options.target.type).async) {  
        console.log('entered')
      options.target.clone(function (clone) {
        clone.set({left: 200, top: 100});
        stage.add(clone);
      });
    }
    else {
      stage.add(options.target.clone().set({left: 100, top: 100}));
    }
}
```

});

When you initialize the shapes to put on the prep area, you can make them selectable:false. In my app, the selectable:false didn't get transferred during the clone (not sure if it was a mistake in my code) - you can also change the properties during clone.

Note - the if(...async) portion of the code is to deal with the fact that I have both SVG and normal shapes in the prep area. If you only have standard fabric shapes, you only need the code contained in the `else` statement.

Comment: thanks. i'll try it even though i'm still not familiar with fabric.

Comment: any chance it can work without fabric? i already wrote my code to make a free drawing in canvas

Comment: The general approach would work without Fabric, but I don't know the specifics of what code you would need. The summary of the approach I took was a) have two canvases, b) use the mouse:down attached to canvas 1 to clone from one to the other. By attaching to canvas 1, clicking the copied shape in canvas 2 will not perform the copy. I highly recommend using Fabric to make your free draw tool, though - it makes it really easy to do lots of stuff.